# Java / Parsing ArrayList Of Strings For New Line And Adding Them To New ArrayList

Tags: java

I am working on a VBScript Obfuscator in Java, I have a simple file reader as shown:

```
public static List<String> read(File file) {

    List<String> content = new ArrayList<>();

    try {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        String line;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            content.add(line + "\n");

        reader.close();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return content;

}
```

I have used this read function to scrape all the data from a VBS file provided:

```
Dim a, b, c, d, e, f

Set a = 0
Set b = 1
Set c = 2
Set d = 3
Set e = 4
Set f = 5
```

So now I am left with an ArrayList with the contents as shown:

```
['Dim a, b, c, d, e, f', Set a = 0, Set b = 1, Set c = 2, Set d = 3, Set e = 4, Set f = 5]
```

**However I am trying to 'rewrite' this List to look more like this:**

```
[Dim a, Dim b, Dim c, Dim d, Dim e, Dim f, Set a = 0, Set b = 1, Set c = 2, Set d = 3, Set e = 4, Set f = 5]
```

**How would I go about doing this?**

So I can then go about the rest of my application, so I need the output file to look something in accordance to thism with the provided input:

```
Dim a
Dim b
Dim c
Dim d
Dim e
Dim f

Set a = 0
Set b = 1
Set c = 2
Set d = 3
Set e = 4
Set f = 5
```

Hopefully I have elaborated enough.. (Sorry if the format is not ideal this is my first post :P)

Also please do not comment about the whole 'if its not broken why fix it' or 'why re-invent the wheel' thing.. I am aware there is a public vbscript obfuscator.

Comment: I don't see a question.

Comment: Sorry I meant to ask how to edit the list to look like the second example of the list..

Comment: check if the line contains "Dim", split around the "," and simply append "Dim" to the front of the strings contained in the array returned from calling split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to find out which condition is necessary to evaluate if a line has a single or many values.

From the example you provided, it might be the presence or absence of commas, or the equal sign.

You could actually do it inside the reader function so you get the proper list in the first place.

Something like this:

```
public static List<String> read(File file) {

List<String> content = new ArrayList<>();

try {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

    String line;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        content.add(getLineContent(line));

    reader.close();

} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

return content;

}

private static String getLineContent(String line, List<String> content) {
    return line.contains(",") 
         ? getMultiValueContent(line)
         : line + "\n";
}

private static String getMultivalueContent(String line) {
    String multivalue;
    String[] values = line.replaceAll(",", "").split(" ");
    String typeValue = values[0];
    IntStream.range(1, values.size)
        .forEach(index -> multivalue = String.join("", multivalue, typeValue, values[index], "\n"))
    return multivalue; 
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @shmosel, check to see if the string contains Dim.

```
int i = 0;
if(line.Contains("Dim"))
    {
    String parts[] = line.Split(",");
    String newString = parts[i];
    content.add(newString + "\n");
    }
```

Make sure the scope of the int is correct this will need to be iterated to get at each "newString".You can do this with you current while() or alternatively do the check for contains.("dim") in another while() beneath your current one.

Comment: Problem is, Chris, he might have another types besides “Dim”, so it’s probably best to rely on a more generic condition such as the presence or absence of commas or equal sign.

Comment: Agreed, i wasn't sure originally if OP only wanted to perform this action for "Dim" mathces, but you are correct why limit it to one specific type when you can build for multiple scenarios.